# semantic ui container segment

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I'm learning semantic ui. But I always confuse about container and segment. I don't know when use container or segment,Those look not different beside margin.
Someone explain it to me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Container and segment are different in the way they look as well as the way they function.

**Look:**

- A segment has the properties of box-shadow, border-radius and border (read: special formatting) that make it look elevated.
- A container looks simpler.
- Note: A basic segment does not have this special formatting.

**Behavior:**

> A container is an element designed to contain page elements to a
>   reasonable maximum width based on the size of a user's screen. This is
>   useful to couple with other UI elements like grid or menu to restrict
>   their width to a reasonable size for display.

- There is a maximum width associated with a container depending on the user size, but a segment does not have this restriction. A segment will take the full width of the space available.
- Note: However you can override this in site.variables:

> Adjusting site breakpoints in site.variables to use custom values will
>   automatically adjust container widths.